# How to get onclicked div's inner html which is inside an iframe?

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, iframe

I have tried with below code but it is not taking current instance of class which is clicked. Instead of that it is showing content of first class which he finds within my iframe.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#framedata').load(function(){
        var iframe = $('#framedata').contents();

        iframe.find(".editContent").click(function(){
            $("#spanid").show();

            var content_edit = iframe.find(".editContent").html();
            //alert(content_edit);
            //var content_edit = x.contentWindow.documentgetElementByClass('editContent').innerHTML;
            $("#spanid").append("<textarea id='editor'>"+content_edit+"</textarea>"); 
        });
        //...etc...
    });
});
```

Thanking you in advance